# Prevent foreach from breaking up each line of output

Tags: shell, tcsh

In TCSH I am trying to tokenize the output of 'ls -alrth' such that each line is a token rather than each 'space-separated word'.

```
> [myneni@moe test]$ ls
>  total 16K 
>  drwxr-x--- 70 myneni soft  12K May  2
> 11:24 ..
> -rw-r--r--  1 myneni soft    0 May  2 11:25 file1
> -rw-r--r--  1 myneni soft    0 May  2 11:25 file2
> -rw-r--r--  1 myneni soft    0 May  2 11:25 file3 
>  drwxr-xr-x  2 myneni soft 4.0K May  2 11:25 . 
> [myneni@moe test]$ foreach i ( `ls -alrth` )
> foreach? echo $i 
> foreach? end 
 total 
 16K 
 drwxr-x--- 
 70 
 myneni 
 soft 
 12K
> 
 May 
 2 
11:24 
 ..
> 
-rw-r--r-- 
1 
myneni 
soft 
0 
May 
2 
11:25
```

Instead I would like to get this output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 myneni soft    0 May  2 11:25 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 myneni soft    0 May  2 11:25 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 myneni soft    0 May  2 11:25 file3 
drwxr-xr-x  2 myneni soft 4.0K May  2 11:25 .
```

The actual command I am attempting to tokenize is output from perforce command where I can get the changelist number and datatime string, but I suspect this would suffice as an example.

Thanks in advance!
-Sachin

Answer (score 0):

To prevent each word from being "tokenized", wrap with a " "

Like:

```
foreach i ( "`ls -alrth`" )
echo $i 
end
```